# Transferring files using UDP sockets in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, file-transfer

I'm fairly new to socket programming in C, so the code below may have a ton of newbie mistakes.
I'm trying to make a client-server application in which the server will transfer a file to the client using an UDP socket. Both the client and the server will run on Linux hosts. It's an assignment, so it has to be done that way. Other client-server communications may use a TCP socket, but the file transfer MUST be via UDP. The program works correctly for small files, but if I try to send a slightly larger file (say, a 600 kb text file), the client will stop receiving the packets, even though the server will send them all. Here's the file transfer part of the server code:

```
   FILE* myFile;
   long fileSize, readBytes, sentBytes, sizeCheck;
   uint32_t encodedFileSize;

   myFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
   if(myFile == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error when opening file.");
      exit(1);
   }   

   fseek(myFile, 0, SEEK_END);
   fileSize = ftell(myFile);
   encodedFileSize = htonl(fileSize);
   rewind(myFile);
   sizeCheck = 0;

   write(myTCPSocket, &encodedFileSize, sizeof(encodedFileSize));

   if(fileSize > 255)
   {
      while(sizeCheck < fileSize)
      {
         readBytes = fread(bufferRW, 1, 256, myFile);
         sentBytes = sendto(sockfdUDP, bufferRW, readBytes, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, udpAddressSize);
         sizeCheck += sentBytes;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      readBytes = fread(bufferRW, 1, 256, myFile);
      sentBytes = sendto(sockfdUDP, bufferRW, readBytes, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, udpAddressSize);
   }

   if(fileSize == sizeCheck)
   {
      printf("Success.\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Fail.\n");
   }
   fclose(myFile);
   fflush(stdout);
   close(sockfdUDP);
```

As you can see, I used a TCP socket to send the client the file size. Here's the client code:

```
   FILE *myFile;
   long receivedBytes, writtenBytes, sizeCheck;
   long fileSize, realFileSize;
   char ack2[5] = "Ok";   
   sockfdUDP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

   read(socketTCP, &fileSize, sizeof(long));

   realFileSize = ntohl(fileSize);

   myFile = fopen(fileName, "wb");

   if(myFile == NULL)
   {
     perror("Error when creating file.");
     exit(1);
   }

   sizeCheck = 0;

   if((realFileSize) > 255)
   {
      while(sizeCheck < (realFileSize))
      {
         receivedBytes = recvfrom(sockfdUDP, bufferRW, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &serv_addr_size);
         writtenBytes = fwrite(bufferRW, 1, receivedBytes, myFile);
         fflush(myFile);
         sizeCheck += writtenBytes;
      }
   }
   else
   {
        receivedBytes = recvfrom(sockfdUDP, bufferRW, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &serv_addr_size);
        fwrite(bufferRW, 1, receivedBytes, myFile);
        fflush(myFile);
   }

   if(realFileSize == sizeCheck)
   { 
     printf("Success.");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Fail.");
   }
   fclose(myFile);
   close(sockfdUDP);
```

The "bufferRW" buffer was originally declared as char bufferRW[256] and passed to the function as an argument. Same goes for other undeclared variables.
Like I said before, the server will (apparently) send the whole file without any issues. However, the client will stop receiving packets after it's written about 423936 bytes (this may vary between executions). It'll just stay at the recvfrom line, without reading anything.

Now, I'm sure the problem is not being caused by a faulty connection since I'm testing both processes on the same host. And before you ask "What is it with the 256 byte packet size?", there's this weird bug that will throw me a segmentation fault on the `realFileSize = ntohl(fileSize);` client line if I use a buffer size of, say, 1500.

Could you please tell me what am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm trying with different file sizes now. It seems to handle files larger than 256 bytes without issue (it enters and exits the while loops correctly on both client and server), but the client will start having problems when the file is bigger than, say, 300 kb.

EDIT 2: I just debugged the program. Apparently, the server sends the entire file before the client can even enter its while loop.

EDIT 3: I think I know what's causing the issue. It seems like if the server sends a bunch of packets before the client starts reading, the client will read up to 278 packets, regardless of their size. If I try sending, say, 279 before the client starts reading it won't read the 279th packet. So if the server sends its packets fast enough, the number of packets that the client hasn't read yet will exceed 278 and the client won't finish reading all of the packets. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I hope you realize that if you're using UDP, you'll have to deal with packet drops and reordering on your own, which you're not currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

1. `long* fileSize` declared a pointer to a long, but in your code, it's pointing nowhere. In fact, it's pointing to a random address. You should declare it as `long fileSize`, and call `read(socketTCP, &fileSize, sizeof(long))` instead.
2. You should check the return value of `read`, `write`, etc, to guarantee they did not fail. For example, [sendto](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) returns -1 on error. You're ignoring this, and incrementing `sizeCheck` with this value anyway.
3. UDP is not a reliable protocol for file transfers, but if you cannot do without it, you better implement some controls that TCP already gives you for free, like packet reordering, data checksum, etc. And that can be a very complex task by itself.
4. Compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra`. The compiler will give you hints about what could be potentially wrong. I see you're still using `*fileSize` in a comparison, which is clearly wrong.
5. <s>After you fix the `*fileSize` issue, your loop-condition is still using the wrong value (due to `fileSize = ntohl(fileSize)`). You need to store this value in another variable, or change your loop-condition to use the real file size.</s>

Regarding your EDIT 3, you need to somehow *synchronise* your client & server, so they can start the transmission at the same time. However, a sender that is much faster than the receiver will still cause packet loss. To solve this, you'll also need to implement packet acknowledgement, and retransmit a packet if the sender doesn't receive an ACK for a respective sent packet after a timeout. This is something TCP already does for you.
A simpler (but not completely reliable) way, would be to slow down the sending process a bit - maybe using `nanosleep` between each call to `sendto`.

Comment: 1. Done. Still not working.
2. Done, apparently both fread and fwrite are working fine. Sendto doesn't throw any errors.
3. Interestingly, when I tested the program with smaller files (yet bigger than 256 bytes), it worked just fine without me doing any of those things. I don't think that's the issue here, seeing that the client isn't even getting all the packets. Those it does get, though, are perfectly ordered.

Comment: On a LAN, you will get proper order, and you probably won't lose UDP datagrams. If you have to go across a cloud, you'll need to worry about order and unreliable delivery.

Comment: Right now I'm testing both the server and the client on the same host, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'd start by eliminating half of the problem. Test the server-side part of your program using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to send your test file(s) over UDP (eg: `nc -vu 127.0.0.1 1234 < file-to-be-sent.txt`). If that works, it means your server is less likely to be the problem. You can run netcat as a server too (eg: `nc -luv 1234 > received-file.txt`).

Comment: Did the netcat thing, console didn't output anything (I'm guessing that's a good thing?). Updated the code with the `long filesize` thing fixed.

Comment: Changing fileSize to an int means you don't use *fileSize anymore, because fileSize is no longer a pointer to an int, but the int itself.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your changes. See points 4 and 5.

Comment: Indeed, missed that when I edited the code posted here. However, when I changed my source file I changed all the pointers to long (otherwise it wouldn't even compile).

Comment: My bad on point 5. You got that right :-) Did your netcat test go well? Transferred the entire file correctly?

Comment: Well, I'm not even sure if that's what happened. Where should the file appear after the netcat test? Linux noob here, y'know.

Comment: If you ran as I cited in my earlier comment, that should have been created in the current directory.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but the file doesn't seem to transfer at all. I'm running nc -vu 127.0.0.1 1234 < path-to-a-file.txt from another directory, and nothing happens.

Comment: Try `echo $?` after you run `nc`. If it prints anything different than 0, it means the last command failed. And that probably means there's no one listening on port 1234.

Comment: It returned 1. However, I think you're trying to test whether the UDP port I'm using is open. I only open the UDP socket using that port when doing the file transfer, after that it closes. And that means it's only open for, like, half a second before the server finishes sending the packets.

Comment: I thought of both using sleep and using Acks. The ack thing worked, but my teacher said we're not allowed to use that. What a pain in the rear.